# Google Authentication with node.js and passport.js always returning 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: node.js, passport.js, google-signin

I'm trying to authenticate user by Google token sent from an Android app. I'm using node.js and passport.

```
var GoogleTokenStrategy = require('passport-google-id-token');
var passport = require('passport');
var User            = require('./models/usersModel.js');

module.exports = function(app) {

passport.use(new GoogleTokenStrategy({
        clientID: "here-is-my-client-id.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    },
    function(parsedToken, googleId, done) {

        User.findOrCreate({ googleId: googleId }, function (err, user) {
            if(err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            if(!user) {
                user = new User({
                    username: googleId
                });
                user.save(function(err) {
                   if(err) console.log(err);
                    return done(err, user);
                });
            } else {
                return done(err, user);
            }
        });
    }
));

app.post('/auth/google',
    passport.authenticate('google-id-token'),
    function (req, res) {
        res.send(req.user? 200 : 401);
    }
);
};
```

However, I only keep getting 401 response and "Unauthorized" message. I double-checked my clientID, I also used https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token to validate the generated token, and everything seems to be ok.

What is more, yesterday, when I did my first tests, it worked. Today, with a new token, it doesn't.

What am I missing here?

Comment: If you're using the implicit method, then I'd say you've likely hard coded an access_token somewhere. If you're not using the implicit method, then it could be your authorization code that was hard coded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was my mistake and the solution here was simple - the only thing I had to do was to set `Content-Type` header to `application/json`.

Different header or no header at all resulted in 401 response.

Comment: How to set that `Content-Type`?